# implement gitlab and gitlab runner with Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

i want to implement CICD with gitlab and i want to do this with docker-compose and i wrote this docker-compose.yml but this isn't work and i cant connect to gitlab web. another way i recive this log from compose log :

```
**gitlab-runner    | **ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0****
```

this is my compose file :

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://192.168.1.96'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 522
        letsencrypt['enable'] = false
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
      - "522:22"
    volumes:
      - ./config/gitlab:/etc/gitlab
      - ./data/gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab
      - ./logs:/var/log/gitlab
    networks:
      - gitlab

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
    volumes:
      - ./config/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - gitlab

networks:
  gitlab:
```

how can i create `config.toml` file and after run compose how to cnfigure my gitlab.
generally help me for implement CICD with this way.

Comment: share also the content of your file in `./config/gitlab-runner/config.toml`. Most probably, the file does not exist. is it ?

Comment: I did same thing (gitlab runner with dind) couple of months ago . Just share more details & you will get the solution

Comment: My guess is that you haven't yet registered your runner (which you wouldn't have done yet if your gitlab-ui isn't up and running). Assuming that's the case, you should comment you running your gitlab-runner until your gitlab-ui is up and running at which point you can register your runner.

Comment: Have you registerd a runner? https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#docker

Comment: What address do you use to access gitlab? Be aware that you should use the exact address that you provide in `external_url` directive. 
It is not necessary to load gitlab and gitlab-runner so errors in gitlab-runner service has nothing to do with gitlab. 
please comment out the gitlab-runner section and run the docker-compose again and copy the logs in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do next steps from **docker-compose.yml** folder:

1. Creat

   $ touch ./config/gitlab-runner/config.toml
2. Edit it with your editor

   $ <your_text_editor> ./config/gitlab-runner/config.toml
3. Save file
4. Restart docker instance

   $ docker-compose restart gitlab-runner

Comment: Describe, please, problem with CI/CD? Or describe layout. I'd help.